# Transforming R code into R style

Tags: r

Is there a way to write the following statement more effectively?
accel is a dataframe.

```
accel[[2]]<- accel[[2]]-weighted.mean(accel[[2]])
accel[[3]]<- accel[[3]]-weighted.mean(accel[[3]])
accel[[4]]<- accel[[4]]-weighted.mean(accel[[4]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative

```
accel[2:4] <- lapply(accel[2:4], function(x) x-weighted.mean(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of doing it.

```
accel[,2:4] = t(t(accel[,2:4]) - apply(accel[,2:4], 2, weighted.mean))
```

---

Corrected following Marek spot - thanks.

**Morale:** Always check your R code before posting!

Comment: This gives wrong results. Subtraction from matrix works by columns no by rows.